# General file paths for replicating shell scripts on any linux OS

Tags: linux, shell, filepath, shortcut, subdirectory

I'm doing a shell script that is intended to be replicated on any user directory. The same script should be able to recognize any user's directories structure. Since I don't know the directory structure of every user, I wasn't able to recognize the parent folder to run some commands inside my script (Find command in the script). I would appreciate so much your help.

As you can see in my code below, I have three different types of paths  `~/Desktop/input_folder/source.txt`,  `~/Desktop/output_folder/FILE_${array[$i]}_${array[$((i+1))]}.txt`, and `../shares/path/FOLDER_WITH_MANY_FILES`.

The third path has a route that I don't know where is located, so I used `../` to tell the script that assume the parent folder. For the first and second route, I used `~/`because the route is in `/home/username/`. Am I doing it right? Do these routes need double commas ("/path/blah") in order to be read it by shell? I would appreciate your help.

Thanks!

**My code:**

```
   #!/bin/bash

#source file location
input=$(cat ~/Desktop/input_folder/source.txt )

#read file
IFS=',' read -r -a array <<< "$input"

        for((i=0;i<${#array[@]}-1;i+=2));do
                #Create the file
                touch ~/Desktop/output_folder/FILE_${array[$i]}_${array[$((i+1))]}.txt


                echo "Search result for these parameters [${array[$i]},${array[$((i+1))]}]: "$'\r' >> ~/Desktop/output_folder/FILE_${array[$i]}_${array[$((i+1))]}.txt

                #Find pattern and save it in file
                find ../shares/path/FOLDER_WITH_MANY_FILES  -name "*${array[$((i+1))]}*" -exec grep -l "${array[$i]}" {} + | tee -a ~/Desktop/output_folder/FILE_${array[$i]}_${array[$((i+1))]}.txt
```

Comment: Both `..` for the Parent directory of the current directory and `~` for the home directory of the user employing the `~` are posix compliant (I'm nearly certain) so you should be good. The only thing here to keep in mind is that `..` is relative to whatever directory you are in when this is executed, so you might end up in an unexpected path unless you are certain about which directory is currently chosen.

Comment: Hi JNevill! thank you for your comment, it is really useful.